# How can I simplify this query?

Tags: sqlite

I have written the following SQLite query:

```
SELECT sum(amount) / (julianday('now', '+1 day') - julianday('2012-08-11')) * 14 AS 'Cost Per Fortnight'
FROM
(
    SELECT "transaction".transamount AS amount
    FROM checkingaccount_v1 AS "transaction"
    JOIN Category_v1 AS category ON "transaction".CategID = category.CategID
    JOIN SubCategory_V1 AS subcategory ON "transaction".SubCategID = subcategory.SubCategID
    WHERE "transaction".transdate BETWEEN date('2012-08-11') AND date('now')
        AND category.categname = 'Food'
        AND subcategory.subcategname = 'Groceries'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT splittransaction.splittransamount AS amount
    FROM splittransactions_v1 AS splittransaction
    JOIN Category_v1 AS category ON splittransaction.CategID = category.CategID
    JOIN SubCategory_V1 AS subcategory ON splittransaction.SubCategID = subcategory.SubCategID
    JOIN checkingaccount_v1 AS "transaction" ON splittransaction.TransID = "transaction".TransID
    WHERE "transaction".transdate BETWEEN date('2012-08-11') AND date('now')
        AND category.categname = 'Food'
        AND subcategory.subcategname = 'Groceries'
) AS costs
```

**I would like to know how I can simplify it. The two queries that are `UNION ALL`ed are quite similar. Some values, such as the literal date, are also duplicated.**

SQLite doesn't appear to support functions, stored procedures or variables. For this particular query, I require SQLite and can't use another programming language (like Perl) to execute it, so please don't suggest other tools/technologies.

If anyone is curious, the query is for a [MoneyManagerEx](http://www.codelathe.com/mmex/) report.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to simplify it a bit:

```
SELECT sum(amount) / (julianday('now', '+1 day') - julianday('2012-08-11')) * 14 AS 'Cost Per Fortnight'
FROM
(
    SELECT transdate, transamount AS amount, CategID, SubCategID
    FROM checkingaccount_v1 AS "transaction"

    UNION ALL

    SELECT transdate, splittransamount AS amount, splittransaction.CategID, splittransaction.SubCategID
    FROM splittransactions_v1 AS splittransaction
    JOIN checkingaccount_v1 AS "transaction" USING (TransID)
)
JOIN Category_v1 AS category USING (CategID)
JOIN SubCategory_V1 AS subcategory USING (SubCategID)
WHERE transdate BETWEEN date('2012-08-11') AND date('now')
    AND categname = 'Food'
    AND subcategname = 'Groceries'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the purpose of this join in the 2nd half of your query?

```
JOIN checkingaccount_v1 AS "transaction" ON splittransaction.TransID = "transaction".TransID
```

I can't experiment against your data, but would a common table expression for the two different data sources work?

```
;WITH AccountTransactions AS
(
    SELECT  transamount AS amount, TransID, 0 As Split, 
            transdate, categname, subcategname
    FROM    checkingaccount_v1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  splittransamount AS amount, TransID, 1 AS Split, 
            transdate, categname, subcategname
    FROM    splittransactions_v1
), TransactionData AS
(
    SELECT  amount, TransID, Split
    FROM    AccountTransactions
    JOIN    Category_v1 AS category ON AccountTransactions.CategID = category.CategID
    JOIN    SubCategory_V1 AS subcategory ON AccountTransactions.SubCategID = subcategory.SubCategID
    WHERE   transdate BETWEEN date('2012-08-11') AND date('now')
        AND categname = 'Food'
        AND subcategname = 'Groceries'
)
SELECT  sum(amount) / (julianday('now', '+1 day') - julianday('2012-08-11')) * 14 AS 'Cost Per Fortnight'
FROM    TransactionData
```

Comment: The `"transaction"` table provides the `transdate` column.

Comment: Thanks; I haven't used CTEs before. Unfortunately, it looks like SQLite doesn't support them.

Comment: The `;` goes at the end of a statement, even in SQL Server: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons and http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/why-i-will-begin-using-semicolons-to-terminate-sql-statements

Comment: Sorry, bad habit. I was in SQL Server land, and most queries I have seen are written without the optional (in MS SQL) terminating semicolon.